# How can I get the hexadecimal functionality of Digital ColorMeter back?

Tags: macos, color

I often used Digital ColorMeter to capture colours as hex codes for web development. For some reason, Lion's version has removed a whole load of functionality, including this. [Some](http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?p=1906324) [people](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13002608&postcount=4) have managed to copy over the Lion version with their Snow Leopard version, but my Mac tells my that it's required by OSX and can't be deleted. Can anyone work out a way to do the method described by these people?

Comment: You can remove the new version with Terminal: `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor\ Meter.app/` However, Snow Leopard DCM crashes in Lion, making the whole endeavour a bit of a fool's errand.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Select *View → Display Values → as Hexadecimal*:

[image: menu in DigitalColor Meter to enable hex display]

Now the main window displays hex values:

[image: DigitalColor Meter in hex view]

Also, *Color → Copy Color as Text* <kbd>⇧⌘C</kbd> will now format the color like `#C8D8E8` (instead of `200 216 232`).

Answer (score 3):

In lieu of DigitalColor Meter, I've been using an [alternative](http://dividtechnology.com/blog/?p=289).

1. Open up AppleScript Editor
2. Enter the words `choose color` and go to Save. Make it an application.
3. You now have a pop-up colour chooser. Unfortunately, there's no inbuilt hex display. Luckily, Waffle Software have made [a plugin](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/) that gives you the hex of any colour.

Comment: Instead of the first two steps, you can download [an application already generated in that way](https://www.robinwood.com/Catalog/Technical/OtherTuts/MacColorPicker/ColorPicker.zip), linked from the bottom of [this document about the Mac OS X Color Picker](https://www.robinwood.com/Catalog/Technical/OtherTuts/MacColorPicker/MacColorPicker.html). And that app even comes with a cool-looking custom icon.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane it lets you pick a color, but it doesn't give you a Hex value for it. When you click on the color you want to analyze, then "OK", the app quits.