# Digital Color Meter not displaying hex values anymore

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the hexadecimal functionality of Digital ColorMeter back?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18353/how-to-get-the-hexadecimal-functionality-of-digital-colormeter-back)

How can I set DigitalColor Meter to show color hex values, like it did before upgrade to Lion?

Comment: I've already asked (and answered!) this question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18353/how-to-get-the-hexadecimal-functionality-of-digital-colormeter-back)

Comment: @Magnakai Good point! If you see something like that, please use the `flag` link under the question and mark it as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @Magnakai: Cool thanks. It seems there's an workaround on your question.