# What tool exists to identify the RGB value of a pixel?

Tags: macos, image-capture

I need to get the RGB for a pixel that is in an image. Under Windows this is easy but is there a way to do this on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 134):

I usually use DigitalColor Meter (in Utilities). As long as it's open, it gives you the RGB values of the pixel below your mouse cursor.

[image]

Comment: The only drawback is that the new Lion Digital Color Meter won't give you hex values. The one in Snow Leopard did.

Comment: @Wheat you can change it to show hex under `View` → `Show values as` → `hexadecimal`

Comment: @koiyu Yes, but you can't set that as the default AFAIK. Really bugs me!

Comment: Anyone know what the difference is between "native" values and "generic" RGB? They are different. I noticed that if I use native colors, they look different on the iOS simulator. Generic seems to be closer.

Comment: @user9290 It's just hidden now, not gone. See how to get hex values here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30834/123184

Comment: See wisbucky's answer below for a complete explanation of *actually* how to do this accurately.

Answer (score 13):

Use the built-in app `/Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor Meter`. Place your mouse pointer over the pixel you want the color of, and DigitalColor Meter will show the RGB values.

Answer (score 9):

You can use macOS' built-in [Digital Color Meter](https://support.apple.com/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac), however there is a very important caveat:

**If you simply use the default settings naively, the values it displays are probably not the values you are looking for.** (This can be an issue for most color dropper tools).

By default, the Digital Color Meter displays the "Native Values", which sounds like the original RGB values, but it's not. "Native Values" actually means the values **after they've been converted to the Color Profile for the current display**. (The Color Profile in use is displayed at the bottom of the Digital Color Meter window.) This is usually going to be a specific Color Profile for your display. For example, my Macbook Pro is set to the "Color LCD" profile.

**Solution**

To get the exact original RGB values before conversion, you need to temporarily change your `System Preferences > Displays > Color > Display Profile` to `sRGB` (which is the most common Color Space, so use `sRGB` unless you know otherwise). Then the Digital Color Meter's Native Values will give you the exact original RGB values that you are looking for.

Another alternative method for web pages is to use the browser inspector and look for the css color value directly.

---

**Details**

You can easily test this for yourself. Go to a [web page that lists CSS web colors and their RGB values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names). Open the Digital Color Meter and set it to Native Values. Scan down the list of colors and compare the Digital Color Meter values with the original values. Probably most of them will not match exactly. (If they all match perfectly, then you probably have set your display to use the sRGB profile).

What's happening is that the dropper can only capture the value after it's been converted to the display's Color Profile.

You can change Digital Color Meter to "Display in sRGB", but that will not always give you the exact original values. That is because it is double converting from original sRGB to display's Color Profile, then back to sRGB. Sometimes there will be rounding error and it will be off by a tiny bit.

The only way to guarantee the exact original is to temporarily change your display to sRGB, because then there will be no conversion at all.

For further reading, [here is an excellent article](https://www.ricciadams.com/articles/osx-color-conversions/).

---

**Example**

Here is an example using DCM on ForestGreen `rgb(34, 139, 34)`. In the first DCM screenshot, you can see that the values are all off, because it is showing the "Native Values" for "Color LCD" profile. In the second DCM screenshot, I've changed it to "Display in sRGB", but one of the values is still off due to double conversion rounding error. In the third DCM screenshot, notice that I've changed my Display to use sRGB color space. Finally it gives the exact original values.

The second row shows what happens if I naively took the wrong `rgb(40, 138, 41)` values and used them. Although you can't really see the difference through human eyes, it's off. And if you repeated the process, you would keep drifting further off.

[image: Digital Color Meter example]

Comment: Re "*If they all match perfectly, then you probably have set your display to use the sRGB profile*"; nope they all match but mine is showing Color LCD too https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCWc0.png (macbook original)

Comment: On Firefox. Though on Chrome it is showing 40, 138, 42 instead of 34, 139, 34.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SpotColor](http://zachwaugh.com/spotcolor/) (recently renamed to [Hues](http://giantcomet.com/hues), more info [here](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/5275045600/hues-and-spot-color))

[image]
[image]

and [HexPicker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/) (which currently has a slight issue with Lion still)

[image]

Comment: This app is no longer available in the Apple store.

Answer (score 0):

[ColorSnapper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorsnapper/id418176775?mt=12) is the best. $4.99 on the Mac App Store.

Just take a look at the [demo video](http://colorsnapper.com/) and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

My current go to tool for this is [xScope App by The Iconfactory](https://xscopeapp.com)

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xscope-4/id889428659?mt=12

It's better for my needs than the built in tool or my previous choice for augmenting the Apple native solution, [Digital Color Picker](http://www.panic.com/%7Ewade/picker/) plug in to extend the Mac OS X color palette.

Specifically, xScope extends to iPadOS, iOS, WatchOS and has many many other features I need in addition to peeping the color values (like looking at a digital design for various colorblindness and accessibility situations). It's used by photographers and designers I respect and has served me well for many years. No affiliation other than a happy paying customer.

Comment: How's this better than Meter?

Comment: It’s unsupported, so it may not be better than meter. What is meter? @Pacerier

Comment: the DigitalColor Meter in Utilities...

Comment: I've added xScope app which goes far past the Apple utility @Pacerier Thanks so much for pointing out the answer in need of better explanation and options.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lighter option to DigitalColor Meter you can check out [Point&Paste](https://github.com/Vaccarini-Lorenzo/Point-and-Paste). It's a free open-source tool that allows you to just place the cursor on the color you want and copy it to the clipboard with a key-binding of your choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.info/newsletter/graphicconverter_en_2023.html).  It has an optional (turns on or off in settings) RGB readout in the window frame that follows the cursor.  It also has a tool represented by an eye-dropper that copies the color value into the foreground color setting.  The eye-dropper, however, averages the colors of the pixels around the point clicked.  But the radius can be adjusted from ten pixels to one (and *one* would mean just the pixel clicked on).

GraphicConverter can be bought from the app store, but [has some limitations](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/mac-app-store).  You can avoid those limitations by getting it directly from the developer.  But you can also convert to the full version if you got it from Apple.

Comment: Could you add a link to the download page or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I use this online color picker: https://pickcoloronline.com

[image: preview]

It's easy to use and I don't have to download any external software. However one disadvantage is that it's not working with Safari. It only works in Chrome.

Comment: I rather think having to download Chrome to make it work classes as having to use 3rd party software. You have contradicted yourself.

Comment: I understand your thoughts. However for me and many other users, Chrome is already the default browser of my choice. In this case I don't have to download anything and this is what I love about the tool.