# getting a color value of a specific point on screen

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I get a color of a specific point on screen with Apple Script?

I would give the point in pixels such as {120,400}. Should I use an external app and "tell" it to find color value of some point or does Apple scripts come with this functionality? It would be the best for my needs not to launch another app.

Comment: You already have an app that can tell you the color of a pixel on the screen: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25421

Comment: The script was based on the colour of pixel. Found a workaround. Thanks anyway!