# How to pick a color with DigitalColor Meter?

Tags: screen-capture, color

I want to pick a color from screen using the DigitalColor Meter. However, I cannot seem to lock the mouse. How am I supposed to use this tool?

Comment: You mean locking position with `⌘`+`L` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the DigitalColor Meter is running, you can pick a color on the current mouse position by using the shortcut:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

It will store the value in the clipboard. The standard is RGB values e.g. 
   255 255 255

If you prefer hexadecimal notation, you can [check this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30834/53299).